# Randomization with SPSS

Tags: spss

Randomization and SPSSS

I have a dataset with 20000 records: the dependedant variable  is given  in  Burned Areas (1) and Not Burned Areas (0). For each case there are 5 dependent variables. One of these independent variables is the fire weather index given as group 1 - group2 -...group 5.

I want to see if the randomly assigned points are by chance or not in burned and not burned areas.

Can I do it with SPSS

For the moment I want to know if SPSS can conduct a randomization test

Comment: Consider asking this question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/